# Conditional format rule "Text Contains" with a "+" misinterpreted as a formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format a bunch of cells containing strings. If the string contains either a `-` or a `+`, the cell should be highlighted in red or green, respectively. However, when just putting a `+` o `-` in the conditional formatting rule it says that the formula is invalid.

If I enclose the `+` or `-` with double or single quotes it does not work unless the cell literally contains `"+"` instead of `+`.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `~` (tilde) to escape `+` (plus sign), `=` (equal sign) and also other special characters like `*` (asterisk) and `?` (question mark) that are used as wildcards.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

**References**
[Apply conditional formatting rules - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en)

Comment: This solution still works in 2023, thanks :)